# Cannot find the JRE for some reason

Tags: classpath, java

I have the following error - and I am getting a 404 problem. I think they are related. Is this a class path error?

> Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;....

Comment: Thanks, what I did was I removed J2ee.jar and that removed the situation.

Comment: resolved rather than removed, but I think you know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

They're not related, the message is just a warning...

It's not saying JRE was not found. It just mentions where did it look for Apache Native, which is an optional speed-up you don't need I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is about the [Tomcat native libraries](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html) which are optional. As the warning states, the native libraries can boost performance. This warning is probably unrelated to your HTTP `404` error. Please provide more detail about your `404` error. What is the url? What `<servlet-mapping>`s and `<filter-mapping>`s do you have defined in `web.xml`?